# Adding a toggle button in jquery ui layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, layout

I am using a jquery layout plugin from http://layout.jquery-dev.net/

I am trying to add a toggle button for all the border panes. But don't know why it's not working. I feel the documentation is not so well written.

Here is my code. Can anyone with experience with the plugin help.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Layout Container with Margins</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/layout-default-latest.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        background: #666;
        width:      100%;
        height:     100%;                   
        padding:    0;
        margin:     0;
        overflow:   auto; /* when page gets too small for container min-width/height */
    }
    #container {
        background: #999;
        min-height: 300px;
        min-width:  600px;
        position:   absolute;
        top:        50px;   /* margins in pixels */
        bottom:     50px;   /* could also use a percent */
        left:       50px;
        right:      50px;
    }
    .pane {
        display:    none; /* will appear when layout inits */
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.ui.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.layout.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#container').layout();
    });

    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myLayout;

$(document).ready(function () {
    myLayout = $('body').layout();

    myLayout
    .bindButton('#closeAllPanes', 'close', 'north')
    .bindButton('#closeAllPanes', 'close', 'south')
    .bindButton('#closeAllPanes', 'close', 'west')
    .bindButton('#closeAllPanes', 'close', 'east');
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="pane ui-layout-center">
        <button id="closeAllPanes">Close All Panes</button>
        <p><b><center>STAGE</center></b></a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="pane ui-layout-north"><i>Header</i></div>
    <div class="pane ui-layout-south"><i>Footer</i></div>
    <div class="pane ui-layout-east"><i>Right Pane</i></div>
    <div class="pane ui-layout-west"><i>Left Pane</i></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error in console?

Comment: yes TypeError: myLayout.bindButton is not a function

Comment: It means layout js is not imported properly.

Comment: checked in firebug the status for jquery.layout.js is Http 304 not modified. Is the code ok for toggle?

Comment: Yes code looks fine to me. Check your import statemets. (HTTP 304 should not be a problem though)